# jquery ui dialog pulls wrong id in dynamically generated list in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an `IEnumerable<MyModel>` dynamically generated list based on user selections being displayed in a JQueryUI Accordian. That part works fine. What I am trying to do is create a proof of concept for a JQueryUI Dialog, where I click on a textbox and the dialog pops up and allows me to enter data. Because I need obviously need unique `id`'s and the content is dynamic, I've used c# to create variables based on the particular instance of the model being passed. This has worked to some extent; a dialog pops up when I click the text box, but I was having trouble with the positioning when I introduced something (`<label for="Dmg">Dmg @(Model.Name)</label>`) to keep track of which instance the dialog was pulling from.

**The problem I see now is, if I have 2 or more objects being passed, the dialog references (in @Model.Name) only the last one listed.**

The same name (whatever is last in the list) appears in that `@(Model.Name)` no matter which textbox I click on. The last one listed also positions correctly while the other ones appear in the top left corner of the document. 
Here is my entire view with JS:

```
@model DnDTracker.Models.Character
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}
@{ string hptxtboxName = "hptextbox" + Model.Name;}
@{ string dialogName = "dialogForm" + Model.Name;}
@{ string formName = "form" + Model.Name;}
<dl class="dl-horizontal">    
    <dt>
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HitPoints)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HitPoints) 
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.HitPoints,new {id=@hptxtboxName})
</dd>
<dt>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AC)
</dt>
<dd>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AC) @Html.EditorFor(x => x.AC)
</dd>
</dl>

@Html.Partial("_HitDiceView", Model.HitDiceList)
@Html.Partial("_SpellSlotsView", Model.SpellSlotList)
@Html.Partial("_AttacksView", Model.AttackList)

<div id=" @(dialogName)" title="+ Dmg/- Healing" class="form-group">
  <form id="@(formName)">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="Dmg">Dmg @(Model.Name)</label>
        <input type="text" name="Hp" id="HP@(Model.Name)" value="0" 
 class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <button type="submit" form="@(formName)" class="btn btn-
 default">Add</button>
        <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the 
dialog button -->
        <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; 
top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    $("#@(hptxtboxName)").click(function () {
        dialog.dialog("open");
    })
});

dialog = $("#@(dialogName)").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 100,
    width: 150,
    modal: true,
    position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: 
"#@(hptxtboxName)",collision:"none" }
});
</script>
```

<strike>I'm not great at browser developer tools so I haven't been able to find the actual dialog html</strike> but I have verified that the text box and the javascript seem to be using the right dynamically generated `id`'s. And doing a quick search I see separate html for each Models dialog div and the JS to address it.

What am I missing or can I troubleshoot?

UPDATE: Here is a full dump of the generated HTML, with 2 objects in the list.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>greedyLumpSoftware</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/Content/themes/base/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Home">DnDTracker</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Character List</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form action="/Account/LogOff" class="navbar-right" id="logoutForm" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="hDY3sKz4NUWdGCYGm7u08wTLkdN7BM37ClIifwWco7SLSW_aUnq8L4rLgaU3mpAikjqMGD8rIpv1Gnwv7BRWwrnpOw4bsjGi9glLqDzXqvhXrQn7X9IPEbjmbguJs_nnMcftQnQDgCl86BMG_bvl2w2" />    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a href="/Manage" title="Manage">Hello xxxxxxx@gmail.com!</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">





<h2>Combat</h2>

<div id="accordion">

        <h3>
            Signum
        </h3>
        <div>
            <p>






<dl class="dl-horizontal">

    <dt>
        HP
    </dt>


    <dd>
        56 <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field HP must be a number." data-val-required="The HP field is required." id="hptextboxSignum" name="HitPoints" type="text" value="56" />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        AC
    </dt>

    <dd>
        17 <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AC must be a number." data-val-required="The AC field is required." id="AC" name="AC" type="number" value="17" />
    </dd>

</dl>

<div>
    <p>
        <div class="tableinner">
            <div class="rowinner">
                <div class="cell single">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="bold left3">
                                Class
                            </th>
                            <th class="middle3">
                                Hit Dice
                            </th>
                            <th class="right3">
                                Remaining
                            </th>
                        </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="left3">
                                    Paladin
                                </td>
                                <td class="middle3">
                                    5d10
                                </td>
                                <td class="right3">
                                    5
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left3">
                                    Warlock
                                </td>
                                <td class="middle3">
                                    1d8
                                </td>
                                <td class="right3">
                                    1
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </p>
</div>














<div>
    <p>
        <div class="tableinner">
            <div class="rowinner">
                <div class="cell single">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="bold left3">
                                Class
                            </th>
                            <th class="middle3">
                                Spell Level
                            </th>
                            <th class="right3">
                                Number of Slots
                            </th>
                        </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="left3">
                                    Paladin
                                </td>
                                <td class="middle3">
                                    1
                                </td>
                                <td class="right3">
                                   4
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left3">
                                    Paladin
                                </td>
                                <td class="middle3">
                                    2
                                </td>
                                <td class="right3">
                                   2
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </p>
</div>




<div>
    <p>
        <div class="tableinner">
            <div class="rowinner">
                <div class="cell single">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="bold left3">
                                Name
                            </th>
                            <th class="middle3">
                                Attack Bonus
                            </th>
                            <th class="right3">
                                Damage
                            </th>
                        </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="left3">
                                   Glaive
                                </td>
                                <td class="middle3">
                                    8
                                </td>
                                <td class="right3">
                                    1d10+5
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left3">
                                   Eldritch Blast
                                </td>
                                <td class="middle3">
                                    7
                                </td>
                                <td class="right3">
                                    1d10+0
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </p>
</div>








<div id="dialogFormSignum" title="+ Dmg/- Healing" class="form-group">
      <form id="formSignum">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="Dmg">Dmg Signum</label>
            <input type="text" name="Hp" id="HPSignum" value="0" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <button type="submit" form="formSignum" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
            <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
            <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $("#hptextboxSignum").click(function () {
            dialog.dialog("open");
        })
    });

    dialog = $("#dialogFormSignum").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 100,
        width: 150,
        modal: true,
        position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: "#hptextboxSignum",collision:"none" }
    });
</script>







            </p>

        </div>
        <h3>
            Xlenith
        </h3>
        <div>
            <p>






<dl class="dl-horizontal">

    <dt>
        HP
    </dt>


    <dd>
        44 <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field HP must be a number." data-val-required="The HP field is required." id="hptextboxXlenith" name="HitPoints" type="text" value="44" />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        AC
    </dt>

    <dd>
        15 <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AC must be a number." data-val-required="The AC field is required." id="AC" name="AC" type="number" value="15" />
    </dd>

</dl>

<div>
    <p>
        <div class="tableinner">
            <div class="rowinner">
                <div class="cell single">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="bold left3">
                                Class
                            </th>
                            <th class="middle3">
                                Hit Dice
                            </th>
                            <th class="right3">
                                Remaining
                            </th>
                        </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="left3">
                                    Rogue
                                </td>
                                <td class="middle3">
                                    6d8
                                </td>
                                <td class="right3">
                                    6
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </p>
</div>














<div>
    <p>
        <div class="tableinner">
            <div class="rowinner">
                <div class="cell single">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="bold left3">
                                Class
                            </th>
                            <th class="middle3">
                                Spell Level
                            </th>
                            <th class="right3">
                                Number of Slots
                            </th>
                        </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="left3">
                                    Rogue
                                </td>
                                <td class="middle3">
                                    1
                                </td>
                                <td class="right3">
                                   4
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left3">
                                    Wizards
                                </td>
                                <td class="middle3">
                                    1
                                </td>
                                <td class="right3">
                                   3
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </p>
</div>




<div>
    <p>
        <div class="tableinner">
            <div class="rowinner">
                <div class="cell single">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="bold left3">
                                Name
                            </th>
                            <th class="middle3">
                                Attack Bonus
                            </th>
                            <th class="right3">
                                Damage
                            </th>
                        </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="left3">
                                   Bow
                                </td>
                                <td class="middle3">
                                    7
                                </td>
                                <td class="right3">
                                    1d6+4
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left3">
                                   FireBolt (Spell)
                                </td>
                                <td class="middle3">
                                    5
                                </td>
                                <td class="right3">
                                    2d10+0
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </p>
</div>








<div id="dialogFormXlenith" title="+ Dmg/- Healing" class="form-group">
      <form id="formXlenith">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="Dmg">Dmg Xlenith</label>
            <input type="text" name="Hp" id="HPXlenith" value="0" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <button type="submit" form="formXlenith" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
            <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
            <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $("#hptextboxXlenith").click(function () {
            dialog.dialog("open");
        })
    });

    dialog = $("#dialogFormXlenith").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 100,
        width: 150,
        modal: true,
        position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: "#hptextboxXlenith",collision:"none" }
    });
</script>







            </p>

        </div>

</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            header:"h3",
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: 'content',
            active: true,
            autoHeight: 'false'
        });
    }

</script>



        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2017 - greedyLumpSoftware</p>
        </footer>
    </div>


    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>



<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"adf5bf45868c4721afdcef8f90801e8a"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:50150/67e6deadba284fad806dfc341087e6bb/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you View Source on the page, what are the values that are being found in the resulting HTML?

Comment: It looks like they are right, but something is obviously off. So for the dialog div, it shows its pulled the right names from: @{ string hptxtboxName = "hptextbox" + Model.Name;}
@{ string dialogName = "dialogForm" + Model.Name;}
@{ string formName = "form" + Model.Name;} etc. The HTML it shows appears to have to have the right names, but is it possible its only displaying ONE of the generated dialog boxes?

Comment: Can you update your question to show the resulting HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: Entire HTML above.

Comment: I moved this to a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/8p7xf9n7/ there are a number of issues in the HTML syntax that should be corrected. I also see re-purposing of `dialog` variable that can be problematic in your script code.

Comment: Keep in mind the asp.net framework is generating some of that html on the fly, which might be why it's kind of ugly. Also, my coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix is to set each dialog to it's own unique variable. For example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/8p7xf9n7/4/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

  $("#accordion").accordion({
    header: "h3",
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: 'content',
    active: true,
    autoHeight: 'false'
  });

  var sigDiag = $("#dialogFormSignum").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 100,
    width: 150,
    modal: true,
    position: {
      my: "left top",
      at: "left bottom",
      of: "#hptextboxSignum",
      collision: "none"
    }
  });

  var xlenDiag = $("#dialogFormXlenith").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 100,
    width: 150,
    modal: true,
    position: {
      my: "left top",
      at: "left bottom",
      of: "#hptextboxXlenith",
      collision: "none"
    }
  });

  $("#hptextboxSignum").click(function() {
    sigDiag.dialog("open");
  });

  $("#hptextboxXlenith").click(function() {
    xlenDiag.dialog("open");
  });

});
```

It doesn't make much of a different, yet I prefer to setup the initialization of elements first and then assign event callbacks. This just helps me avoid confusion and ensures that all elements are created before trying to assign actions.

I would also advise moving the JavaScript into one block and put this in the `<head>` versus throughout the HTML. If you plan to keep it in the HTML (put it at the end), you do not need to wrap it in `$(function(){});`.

Comment: This is what I was starting to suspect but I'm so new to JS and JQuery i wasnt sure If I was barking up the right tree. As far as initialization and callback order: I don't have a choice because it is generating different java script depending on how many D&D characters the user chooses, who data the user inputs as well, so I can't predict their names. But I can use techniques similar to creating  attribute ID's to make unique variable names. Anyway, this fixed it, thanks! I almost gave up and moved on to something else.

Comment: I do understand, this is why I do not use ASP.NET or MVC, even when they do have a lot of neat tools and features. JavaScript is purely client side, so it only interacts with the resulting HTML. This just means you need to be mindful of that as you write the code that will generate that HTML. Also once the HTML is rendered and passed off to the browser, that is where your JS/jQuery becomes helpful. AJAX is the tool that JS/jQuery uses to gather more data or push details back to your server side scripts.